# How can I reduce the overall height of an asp.net gridview control?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to reduce the overall height of this gridview so there aren't so many "empty rows" at the bottom.  I tried setting the Height attribute. I also tried setting the PagingSize to a smaller number and setting the AllowPaging Attribute=true

The datasource will return a variable number of rows, but the gridview needs to be fixed height.  Right now it's taking up a lot more vertical real estate than any max number of HearingInfo would even reach.  In other words, there is enough space at the bottom for at least 10 more rows,  but there would never ever be 10 more rows.

I haven't worked with ASP.net web controls in a while...

```
        <asp:GridView ID="gvHearingInfo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableModelValidation="True" 
            ShowHeader="False" Width="100%" GridLines="Vertical" 
            Height="50px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Authority" HeaderText="Authority" 
                    SortExpression="Authority">
                <ItemStyle Width="144px" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                    BorderColor="Black" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PublicHearing" HeaderText="PublicHearing" 
                    SortExpression="PublicHearing" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="431px" BorderColor="Black"  />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HearingDate" HeaderText="HearingDate" 
                    SortExpression="HearingDate" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="93px" BorderColor="Black"  />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HearingTime" HeaderText="HearingTime" 
                    SortExpression="HearingTime" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="92px" BorderColor="Black"  />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DistrictTelephone" HeaderText="DistrictTelephone" 
                    SortExpression="DistrictTelephone" >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"  Width="94px" BorderColor="Black"  />
                </asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: a piece of advice.. Customize the paging .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Results.DataSource = dataView;

Results.DataBind();

foreach(GridViewRow row in this.Results.Rows) 
{
   if (row.Equals(""))
     {
      Results.Rows[0].Visible = false;
     }

}
```

or you will have to use the GridView.RowDataBound Event but I think the code should do the work...